# How to get all jar from classpath of Tomcat application?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, classpath

I need to write new module, which is able to get all application's jar in runtime.

I try do it with getting inforimation with `Classloader.getSystemClassloader()`, but `catalina.bat` in Tomcat override variable of classpath.

So, next idea was to recursively iterate through all the **target** folders and look for a **lib** folder. In my module I wrote :

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        File currentDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")); // current directory
        System.out.println("Cur dir: " + currentDir);
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
    }
}
```

I got this result:

> Cur dir: C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\jar

This is path to my war, which I added to application. But I need the path to the application itself.

So, have you any idea?

Answer (score 4):

**Java EE applications have customized `ClassLoader` hierarchy.**

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        ClassLoader effectiveClassLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL[] classPath = ((URLClassLoader) effectiveClassLoader).getURLs();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this return the jar of THIS module. My problem - get jar from another application, adding my war with this code to deployed wars to Tomcat

Comment: You cannot do that. You can only access current ClassLoader, or Java EE classloader, not not ClassLoader from a different application using standard way. Maybe there can be some custom Tomcat way...

Answer (score 0):

You want the classloader for your application, not Tomcat.  Get the classloader for the servlet - this.getClass().getClassLoader() or MainServlet.getClassLoader() should both work.